# Jquery post method does not work

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

Here is the jquery code:

```
$(function () {
            $("#personCreate").click(function () {

                var person = getPerson();

                // poor man's validation
                if (person == null) {
                    alert("Specify a name please!");
                    return;
                }

                // take the data and post it via json
                $.post("banner/save", person, function (data) {
                    // get the result and do some magic with it
                    alert("Post");
                    var message = data.Message;
                    $("#resultMessage").html(message);
                });
            });
        });
```

The controller:

```
            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Save(PersonModel person)
            {
                string message = string.Format("Created {0} in the system",person.Name);
                return Json(new PersonViewModel {Message = message });
            }
```

When I click the button there is no action. The post never directs to the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Hardcoded urls like this always look suspicious:

```
$.post("banner/save", ...
```

When working with urls make sure you always use URL helpers to generate them:

```
$.post("@Url.Action("save", "banner")", ...
```

Other things you should be looking for is the console tab in [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) as it will provide you with a valuable information about the AJAX request: what exactly is being sent to the server and what is being received and hopefully point to the error.

Also you haven't shown this `getPerson()` function but at the end of the day the object being posted should look like this:

```
var person = { prop1: 'value 1', prop2: 'value 2', .... };
```

where obviously Prop1, Prop2, ... are properties of the `PersonModel`.

Another thing you should be careful about is this `#personCreate` button. If this is a submit button or an anchor link you should ensure to cancel the default action by returning `false` in the click handler or your ajax might never have the time to execute:

```
$("#personCreate").click(function () {

    // ... the AJAX request here

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how your routing is set up, but you aren't passing the `person` variable in the right manner.

If you need to send `banner/save/#` (where `#` is the value of `person`) you need

```
$.post("banner/save/" + person, function (data) {
```

If you need to send `banner/save?person=#` (ditto on `#`) you need

```
$.post("banner/save", {person: person}, function (data) {
```

If you just pass the value, jQuery will run `jQuery.param` on it, which will result in an empty string sent to the server.  Obviously this won't call your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is that the event is not attached correctly to the button: have you tried doing something like this?

To be sure that the event is fired you should use firebug

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#personCreate").click(function () {

                var person = getPerson();

                // poor man's validation
                if (person == null) {
                    alert("Specify a name please!");
                    return;
                }

                // take the data and post it via json
                $.post("banner/save", person, function (data) {
                    // get the result and do some magic with it
                    alert("Post");
                    var message = data.Message;
                    $("#resultMessage").html(message);
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: Using `$(function(){})` is a shortcut for `$(document).ready()`